# Baby Rudin vs. Abbott

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I am considering Stephen Abbott's [Understanding Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950605) and Walter Rudin's [Principles of Mathematical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007054235X). I am looking for a comparison between the two that addresses both of the following matters,

- Is one of the two substantially more mathematically rigorous than the other?
- Does one include substantially more challenging problems?
- Which provides a better introduction to Real Analysis?

**Follow-up question:**

- Would someone who has worked through Abbott's book be at a disadvantage compared to someone who has completed Rudin's text?

Comment: Rudin is an industry standard in rigor by far for Real Analysis.

Comment: I don't know Abbott's book, but my money is on Rudin.

Comment: @Daniel: I can see that you're enthusiastic, but: is it really helpful to voice on opinion on a comparison of two texts when you're not familiar with one of the texts?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark It's a testimony to the quality of Rudin's books, nothing more.

Comment: As for exercises, this is sure relevant: http://abstrusegoose.com/12

Comment: @JosuéMolina Let's worry about the mathematical content.

Comment: I personally dislike Rudin and every opportunity I have I state how awful the book is. It does not contain enough material, its material is stated in cases which are not very general (and then you have to learn everything again from a good source, so why bother in the first place), it is too coarse in its geometry and intuition, and its examples are borderline idiotic (for instance, when defining derivative he exemplifies by differentiating $x \mapsto x^2$). Never ever say yes to Rudin.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They are both rigorous in that they both give complete proofs of their results. Rudin's problems on the other hand are challenging to newcomers. Abbot's problems are on a much lower level than Rudin's. I love Rudin's books, but there are mixed opinions on whether they should be used as introductions. I used Principles after my first year of analysis and loved it. I'd say first work through Abbot because he will likely provide more motivation. Later, get Rudin and push your boundaries of understanding. You might just become an analyst after that approach. It's what happened to me.

Answer (score 25):

You think you are asking just a simple question but you are adding kerosene to the flame of  Pro-Rudins vs Anti-Rudins :)
Any ways I have read both books and here are my feelings

(1) Rudin definitely has really good, challenging problems

(2) Rudin goes directly to the point

(3) Rudin gives you the opportunity to think on your feet and fill the gaps

That said coming from a normal math background, Rudin was a tough read
for me. Abbott's book was quite a good supplement for some chapters.
But for me Pugh's Real Analysis and Apostol Analysis was the best supplement.
My strategy was to read and re-read Rudin and give some critical time $t_{c}$
to see if I understand a concept. If that doesn't happen $t>t_{c}$, I refered to
the other books. Towards the end of the course, I came to know Terry Tao's book
and I have to say it was a pleasure to read. Good luck, you can always pick one
book and refer to the others when you need to. You need to have a general idea
of where you are going but you don't have to follow every route

Comment: Related (Pugh vs Rudin) : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252705/rudin-against-pugh-for-textbook-for-first-course-in-real-analysis

Answer (score 7):

Can't do better than read "Bolzano Bourbaki's" [review of Baby Rudin on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/review/R23MC2PCAJYHCB/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=007054235X&nodeID=283155&store=books).

Comment: For some reason, the older I get the more that review annoys me. I think it's his dismissal (and seeming lack of understanding) of mathematical motivation. Does anyone else feel that way?

Comment: I think his understanding of what an "application" is sub-par (true for most mathematicians). However, I think his plan of studying Rudin a good one, and his encouragement to keep going even when it gets hard is sorely needed today.

Comment: Yeah for sure. I suppose most students looking at basic analysis books aren't used declaring war on math books. His pep is amusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, that review is childish and offensive, actually. Pity that so many people believe mathematics to be "a contest", or want it to be.

Comment: "Or you could just change your major back to engineering. It's more money and the books always have lots of nice pictures." hahah