# Analysis Textbook like Zorich

Tags: analysis, book-recommendation

I'm an undergraduate student currently studying mathematical analysis.

Our professor uses Zorich's Mathematical Analysis, but I found the text too difficult to understand.

After exploring some textbooks, I found that Abbott was easier to follow, so I studied Abbott until I realized that there's a significant amount of content in Zorich that Abbott doesn't cover.

So I was wondering if there's a book out there that covers as much content as Zorich but is more readable?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Perhaps Courant and John's multi-volume [Introduction to Calculus and Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Calculus-Analysis-Classics-Mathematics/dp/354065058X)

Answer (score 2):

Herbert Amann's analysis which has three volumes is more detailed than zorich's analysis.However, I think it is too difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

You may find Rudin's analysis texts *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* and *Real and Complex Analysis* to be useful, although various analysis textbooks will cover slightly different material.

A discussion related to Zorich/Rudin/Abbott can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1003791/669798).

Answer (score 0):

True that Zorich is difficult to understand.
BUT I still think if you go through with it, you will learn a lot in the end.
However, I think there’s also an other book you could consider about, which is **Mathematical Analysis** written by Apostol.Or, consider Courant’s book.
They are both good books.
Good luck!

Comment: By "Courant's book", did you mean Courant & John's "Introduction to Calculus and Analysis" Volumes I and II? (The latest Springer reprint is split into 3 books, with Volumes I, II/1, and II/2).